# replace text with javascript on amp page

Tags: javascript, html

I want to replace some text using javascript on AMP pages
I tried many ways all of them didn't work
I also tried amp-script and it was not able to accept custom javascript
I usually use innerHTML and the browser tells me it's not supported in amp-script

`document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/hello/g, 'hi');`

Is there a way to change text using javascript on AMP pages?
thanks

I tried AMP-script

```
<amp-script width="200" height="100" script="hello-world">

</amp-script>

<script id="hello-world" type="text/plain" target="amp-script">
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/hello/g, 'hi');
</script>
```

I also tried amp-bind
It was expected that everything would work fine. Indeed, the JavaScript replaces the texts, but after examining the page on Google Console, it tells me that the AMP pages have a problem

Comment: What are you _really_ trying to do, because allowing you to replace the entire page body for an AMP page would be quite incredible.

Comment: Thank you
I don't want to replace the entire text
I just want to replace some phrases
One or two words max

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific: the whole reason you're creating an AMP page is because you want the fastest possible content delivery, including not running content-modifying scripts. You want the page to already be what your users should see, so: what are you _actually_ trying to do? Change which words for what? Are you doing location based replacements, time based replacements, etc?

Comment: I put some codes in the content to make it awsom, for exmpl `[code]` , then I change it with JavaScript.
Unfortunately, these symbols appear on AMP pages because JavaScript is not present.
All I want is to hide those codes in AMP as well.

Comment: So don't use text for that, use a normal HTML element like `<span class="awesome"></span>`. It'll render as nothing on the AMP page, and on your better, non-AMP page you can trivially find those elements and assign their `.textContent`